# xp_cmdshell called from procedure WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to understand details of wrapping xp_cmdshell functionality in user defined stored procs, so that other users can just be given execute permission to the stored procs rather than xp_cmdshell.

The steps in this scenario are:

1. xp_cmdshell is already enabled and a xp_cmdshell proxy has been created
2. A user with db_owner membership creates a stored proc WITH EXECUTE AS
   OWNER which calls xp_cmdshell
3. The user executes the stored proc and therefore executes arbitrary shell code

This is unexpected to me.  I would not expect a user with only db_owner to be able to achieve this.  (Obviously assuming xp_cmdshell has already been enabled by a sysadmin.)

When the database owner is changed from sa to another low privileged login, then the user stored proc is no longer able to call xp_cmdshell.

```
USE MASTER;
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
CREATE LOGIN testuser WITH PASSWORD = 'password', CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
CREATE LOGIN dummyuser WITH PASSWORD = 'password', CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
SELECT * from sys.credentials WHERE NAME LIKE '%cmdshell%';
-- returned: 101 ##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account## .....

USE testdb;

EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa';  
CREATE USER testuser FOR LOGIN testuser;
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER testuser;

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'testuser';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testproc]
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
    SELECT SUSER_NAME() as [SUSER_NAME()], USER_NAME() as [USER_NAME()];  
    exec xp_cmdshell 'echo %time%';
GO

SELECT SUSER_NAME() as [SUSER_NAME()], USER_NAME() as [USER_NAME()];  

EXEC dbo.testproc; 
-- returned: sa dbo  proving that the call to xp_cmdshell has succeeded

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'echo %time%';
-- returned: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell'

REVERT

EXEC sp_changedbowner 'dummyuser';  
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'testuser';
EXEC dbo.testproc; 
-- returned: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell'
-- proving that the sysadmin role of the database owner is relevent

REVERT
```

Note that I have not granted execute xp_cmdshell permission to any particular user.

I thought that enabling xp_cmdshell was ok if care was taken to only grant execute xp_cmdshell permission carefully, but my example seems to show otherwise.

Since a sysadmin is often a database owner, does this example show a serious security problem, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: IMHO,this is great security bug. Thank you for reporting this. Upvoted.

Comment: @sepupic and John: no security bug. See my answer for details :-)

Answer (score 3):

> does this example show a serious security problem, or am I misunderstanding something?

You are misunderstanding what is actually going on here.

> the database owner is changed from sa to another low privileged login, then the user stored proc is no longer able to call xp_cmdshell.

That is true in this case, but that is merely due to how you did (or more accurately: did not) configure things (more on that in a moment).

> I thought that enabling xp_cmdshell was ok if care was taken to only grant execute xp_cmdshell permission carefully,

It is.

> but my example seems to show otherwise.

I would disagree with that. This is just a matter of not understanding the security mechanism, and this does happen to be a tricky case of it, so that is quite understandable.

---

A few things:

1. `EXECUTE AS OWNER` is not specifically the issue. You could have done `EXECUTE AS N'dbo'` to get the same effect.
2. The database being owned by a `sysadmin` is not specifically the issue. You could have done `EXECUTE AS N'other'` where `other` is the name of a User that is associated with a Login that has a User in `[master]` that has been granted execute on `xp_cmdshell` to get the same effect.
3. No, server level permissions are not being granted. To prove this, add the following two lines to your test stored procedure:

   ```sql
   EXEC sp_configure N'allow updates', 1; RECONFIGURE;
   SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions;
   ```

   Go ahead and change the db owner back to `sa` and execute the proc. You will get errors on the `sp_configure` and the `RECONFIGURE`, *and* you will only get 1 row back from `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, your session's row, because you do not have the `VIEW SERVER STATE` server level permission, something `sa` definitely has.

What you are experiencing is a function of two things:

1. You enabled the proxy account which lets non-sysadmins accomplish this *if* they have execute permission (not sure why you enabled this, unless you don't want to be using the SQL Server service account, which is a good idea, but doesn't work for sysadmins)
2. the DB was owned by a login that was associated with a user present in `master` that was granted permission to exec `xp_cmdshell` (this associated is derived from the `EXECUTE AS` combined with the DB ownership)

To prove this, exec the following (at the end of your current test code in the question, with `dummyuser` owning the DB):

```sql
REVERT;
USE [master];
CREATE USER [dummyuser] FOR LOGIN [dummyuser];
GO
GRANT EXEC ON xp_cmdshell TO [dummyuser];
USE [testdb];
```

Then do:

```sql
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'testuser';
EXEC dbo.testproc;
```

and you will now, instead of getting the permission denied error, either have success with `xp_cmdshell`, or you will get the following error if the proxy account is not configured:

> Msg 15153, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line YYYYY [Batch Start Line XXXXX]
>   The xp_cmdshell proxy account information cannot be retrieved or is invalid. Verify that the '##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##' credential exists and contains valid information.

Even better would be to do the following, which removes the permission from `dummyuser`, creates a new low-privileged account, and grants *that* account the `xp_cmdshell` permission:

```sql
USE [master];
CREATE LOGIN [cmdshell] WITH PASSWORD = 'password', CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
CREATE USER [cmdshell] FOR LOGIN [cmdshell];
GRANT EXEC ON xp_cmdshell TO [cmdshell];

REVOKE EXEC ON xp_cmdshell FROM [dummyuser];

USE [testdb];
CREATE USER [cmdshell] FOR LOGIN [cmdshell];
```

*And then*, change the `EXECUTE AS` clause in the stored procedure to be `WITH EXECUTE AS 'cmdshell'`. Execute the proc again and you will either have success or the proxy account error if it isn't set up. In this case:

1. the database owner does not have the permission
2. you aren't tied in any way to a `sysadmin` login.

This works because the `EXECUTE AS` user is associated with a login that has a user in `master` that has been granted execute on `xp_cmdshell`.

ALSO, this behavior is most likely tied to the object (i.e. `xp_cmdshell`) truly existing in the `mssqlsystemresource` database. You can't create an object in `[master]`, grant a user (the same being used as the `EXECUTE AS` user of the stored procedure, even if that user is `dbo` / `OWNER` *and* the database is owned by `sa`) `EXEC` on the user proc in `[master]`, and have it work (not without enabling `TRUSTWORTHY`, which [you shouldn't do](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/)). Not even if the user stored procedure in `[master]` is marked as a system stored procedure (I've tried).

Of course, ideally you would use [Module Signing](https://ModuleSigning.Info/) to take care of the permission instead of `EXECUTE AS` (either associate with `sysadmin` server role to use SQL Server service account, or associate with user in `[master]` that has been granted `EXECUTE` on `xp_cmdshell` to use proxy account, assuming that it has been configured).

Comment: Really appreciate the detail and style of your answer. I’ll try running your examples tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 2):

`xp_cmdshell` can be executed without direct execute permissions in an sa-owned database if the [`cross database ownership chaining`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-cross-database-access-in-sql-server) at the server level, `DB_CHAINING` database option for the `testdb` database, or `EXECUTE AS OWNER` is specified in the proc. These are all non-default configurations and are off by default. Importantly, one should not allow non-sysadmin role members to create dbo-owned objects in an sa-owned database to avoid escalation of privileges.

Although using `xp_cmdshell` in T-SQL in general is a dubious practice, `xp_cmdshell` can be encapsulated in user stored procedures securely by [signing the stored proc with a certificate](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html). This encapsulation avoids granting direct permissions execute to `xp_cmdshell`.

Comment: No, I executed OP's code and I have **no cross database ownership chaining at the server level** and of course **the code does not mark testdb as trustworthy**

Comment: @sepupic, you are right. The `EXECUTE AS OWNER` is the culprit here.

Comment: Execute as owher without TRUSTWORTHY on a database does not add any additional permission OUTSIDE current database, moreover, for any other database it will throw an error "the database principal...cannot access <another database>", so it's a BUG

Comment: Thanks for all info and good advice, but I want to focus on observed behaviour rather than alternatives for now. In summary, you are confirming that: If a DB is owned by a sysadmin and xp_cmdshell is enabled then any user who has permission to create a stored procedure can then call arbitrary shell code? Realistically does that mean that in practice DBs should almost never be owned by sysadmins? That has not been my experience and is not well documented on xp_cmdshell docs.

Comment: @JohnRees, I'm saying any user who has permission to create a dbo-owned stored procedure in an sa-owned database (not any just sysadmin role member) can result in elevated permissions. I used to suggest `sa` for user database ownership but now know better and use a SQL login designated for that purpose.

Comment: @JohnRees and Dan: while I agree with not having DBs owned by a login that's in the `sysadmin` role, this explanation is incorrect. The issue is unrelated to Cross-DB Ownership Chaining. There are no `sysadmin` permissions being granted here, merely the `EXECUTE` permission on `xp_cmdshell` (as a _non_-`sysadmin`, hence the proxy account being used) as a result of the login tied to the `EXECUTE AS` user having an associated user in `master` that was granted `EXEC` on `xp_cmdshell` (plus most likely `xp_cmdshell` residing in `mssqlsystemresource`). Please see my answer for details.